# Windows network share application deployment automation

Tags: ansible, deployment, windows

We have a historically grown setup of interface applications that needs to be  inventorized and cleaned up. Afterwards deployment should be automated and application versions somehow documented.

My problem is that this setup is on a Windows network share only accessible from my work computer (Windows 7).
There is currently no way to change that setup.

Tools that I already looked at are Puppet, Capistrano, Octopus Deploy, RapidDeploy and Ansible. The last one seems to be exactly what I need, but is only available for Linux.

Which tool can be recommended to be used for this task?

Comment: Chef has a native management of Windows and is Free, pay options are mainly the graphical ui and reporting bits, you can start without it. The way of operating is different than ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Otter](http://inedo.com/Otter) it's basically the only Configuration management/Infrastructure as Code tool with native Windows support or Possibly [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster) as well which is more on the release coordination deployment automation side of things.

If you're a Windows heavy shop definitely take a look at the tools mentioned on the [Winops wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinOps) - will probably help point you in the right direction.